# ¿Cómo imputar valores en función al máximo de otra variable? En R

Tags: r, group-by, imputar

Tengo el siguiente data frame.

```
df<-data.frame(PERSONA=c("A","A","A","B","B","B"),
               AÑO=c(2010,2011,2012,2010,2011,2013),
               VALOR=c(NA,2,3,3,NA,1))

df
  PERSONA  AÑO VALOR
        A 2010    NA
        A 2011     2
        A 2012     3
        B 2010     3
        B 2011    NA
        B 2013     1
```

Y deseo imputar los valores `NA` con el valor que se obtuvo en el máximo año. Es decir, que quede de la siguiente manera.

```
df
  PERSONA  AÑO VALOR
        A 2010     3
        A 2011     2
        A 2012     3
        B 2010     3
        B 2011     1
        B 2013     1
```

El `NA` de la persona A del año 2010 imputado con el valor del máximo año. Es decir, con 3 (Año 2012). Y el `NA` de la persona B del año 2011 imputado con el valor del máximo año. Es decir, con 1 (Año 2013).

Uso la siguiente sintaxis, pero creo que es una pasada monstruosa y horrible.

```
tab1<-df %>% select(PERSONA,AÑO, VALOR) %>% filter(!is.na(VALOR)) %>% 
  group_by(PERSONA) %>% summarise(va=max(AÑO)) 

df<-df %>% select(PERSONA,AÑO, VALOR) %>% inner_join(tab1,by=c("PERSONA","AÑO"="va")) %>%
  select(PERSONA,VALOR) %>% right_join(df, by="PERSONA")


df$VALOR.y<-ifelse(is.na(df$VALOR.y),df$VALOR.x,df$VALOR.y)

df$VALOR.x<-NULL
```

Uso el `select()` porque en el data frame hay más variables que `PERSONA`,`AÑO` y `VALOR`.
Asimismo, este proceso lo tengo que hacer para 43 variables. Así que no es nada eficiente lo que he hecho.

¿Cómo podría darle solución de una manera más ordenada y eficiente? Ya que necesariamente tendría que ponerlo dentro de un `for` o un for implícito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con R base:

```
# Obtenemos el último año con valor de cada persona
maximos <- aggregate(AÑO ~ PERSONA, df[!is.na(df$VALOR),], max, na.rm=TRUE)

# Obtenemos el valor de dichos años
valores_reemplazo <- merge(df, maximos, by = c("PERSONA", "AÑO"))

# Join del df original más los valores máximos
new_df <- merge(df, valores_reemplazo, by = c("PERSONA"), all.x = TRUE)
new_df$VALOR.x <- ifelse(is.na(new_df$VALOR.x), new_df$VALOR.y, new_df$VALOR.x)

# reemplazamos los valores NA y normalizamos el df
new_df <- setNames(new_df[, 1:3], c("PERSONA", "AÑO", "VALOR"))
```

Comment: Al usar `aggregate(VALOR ~ PERSONA, df, max, na.rm=TRUE)` no me estoy quedando con el máximo por persona y año, sino solo con el máximo por persona.

Comment: Pero esta bien, la idea es reemplazar los NA por el máximo de cada persona

Comment: La cuestión es reemplazar los `NA`, por el valor del año máximo de cada persona.

Comment: Si, eso es lo que entendí y creo que el código lo resuelve, aunque  se me puede estar escapando algo

Comment: Quizá no me haya hecho entender, perdón. Pero voy a cambiar la última fila del data frame. Y la solución deseada.

Comment: Lo he corregido.

Comment: Ahora si entiendo, no es el máximo por persona, es el valor del año máximo por persona que no sea NA, ok, dejamelo pensar..

Comment: Muchas gracias. Quedo atento.

Comment: Listo, ciertamente con R base es algo más largo, yo calculo que una solución con dplyr sería más concisa y clara.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Pero la solución con R base es más sencilla para proyectarlo a más variables con un for. O con una función. o al menos eso creo.

Comment: Muchas gracias nuevamente. He logrado convertirlo en función para poder aplicarlo a mis otras variables. Muchísimas gracias Patricio.

Answer (score 2):

## Actualización

Este código regresa la tabla que pones en la solución y creo que funciona:

> Editado: ahora no falla cuando el NA está en el último año y toma el último año no NA

```
df %>% 
  group_by(PERSONA) %>%
  mutate(VALOR = ifelse(is.na(VALOR), 
                        VALOR[AÑO == max(AÑO[!is.na(VALOR)], na.rm = TRUE)],
                        VALOR))


# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   PERSONA [2]
  PERSONA   AÑO VALOR
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 A        2010     3
2 A        2011     2
3 A        2012     3
4 B        2010     3
5 B        2011     1
6 B        2013     1
```

El trabajo pesado lo hace `VALOR[AÑO == max(AÑO)]`. Con `[]` hago un subet de `VALOR` cuando se la condición en otra columna. Es una mezcla de `tidyverse` con R base y funciona muy bien porque dentro de la llamada de `mutate` las columnas del data.frame se presentan como vectores (algo parecido a lo que tendríamos con un `with()`) y se puede hacer cualquier operación ahí dentro.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Pero al hacer el group_by sólo obtendrá el máximo por persona. Lo que deseaba es el máximo por persona y por año.

Comment: Ah! Claro, tomar el valor del último AÑO. Puse otra respuesta.